# How to scrape second page after form input Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have this code that enters a zip code on the first page, but I am getting stuck on how to scrape the second page. I just want to collect all the fields in the form and print them to a csv. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried using xpath as well as element.id. The second page has a dynamic url so I can't reference directly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = option)
driver.get("https://www.thegeneral.com")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "free-quote-zip")))
element.click()
element.clear()
element.send_keys("63013")
element.submit()
def click_through_to_new_page(link_text):
  link = browser.find_element_by_link_text('my link')
  link.click()
  def link_has_gone_stale():
    try:
      # poll the link with an arbitrary call
      link.find_elements_by_id('doesnt-matter')
      return False
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
      return True
  wait_for(link_has_gone_stale)
results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//[@id="autoInsurance"]")
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill out the form as follow..

```
 import time
from asyncio import wait_for

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = option)
driver.get("https://www.thegeneral.com")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "free-quote-zip")))
element.click()
element.clear()
element.send_keys("63013")
element.submit()

time.sleep(5)
file = open('csvfile.csv','w')
file.write(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"content_area\"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/form/div[6]/label").text)
autoinsurance_options = driver.find_element(By.ID, "autoInsurance").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "option")
for option in autoinsurance_options:
    file.write(option.text + "\n")

time.sleep(5)
file.write(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"content_area\"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/form/div[7]/label").text)
own_home_options = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "ownsHomeFlag").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "option")
for option in own_home_options:
    file.write(option.text + "\n")

//time.sleep(5)
//driver.find_element(By.ID, "autoInsurance").send_keys("No")
//driver.find_element(By.NAME, "ownsHomeFlag").send_keys("Rent")
//driver.find_element(By.ID, "emailAddress").send_keys("abc@gmail.com")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I also wanted to print the fields to a .csv would I just need to do print () and then the name or id? My end goal is to get all the values for each field printed to a .csv file. I appreciate your help and quick response!

Comment: Can you share a sample output?

Comment: Something like this the field as a heading with the question underneath and the other column with the options for each question. Sorry I don't think it pastes well
                                 
Have you had auto insurance Yes, no, No overseas Military Deployment
Type of Residence                          Rent, Own Home, Own Condo, Own Mobile Home, Other

Comment: @Codyjane, I have updated my answer and printed the all fields under those dropdowns

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help! I have been stuck on this part for awhile, thanks for your kindness and time!!

Comment: I hope it will help you to move forward in your project. Best wishes for you!!

Comment: sorry one last question, how would I export that to a csv? thanks again

Comment: Updated the answer, Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, the only issue is that it is printing the answer selections but not the actual question how would I add that in? Thank you

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! but the results still seem to be printing without the question.

Comment: Following line in the answer is printing the question
file.write(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"content_area\"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/form/div[6]/label").text).
Working fine for me

Comment: This is the output from my csv file
Have you had auto insurance in the last 5 years?
Yes
No
No, overseas Military deployment
Type of Residence?
Rent
Own Home
Own Condo
Own Mobile Home
Other

Comment: Thanks I'll try again! Appreciate your help :)

Comment: On the third page I am having an issue getting the radio button to select, any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? radioButtons = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'sr_F[0]')

radioButtons[1].click()

Comment: sr_M[0] is for MALE and sr_F[0] is for email. if you want to click male just do driver.find_element(By.ID, "sr_M[0]").click(). and for female do driver.find_element(By.ID, "sr_F[0]").click()

Comment: Thanks, for some reason that isn't working? I had tried that before also. Not sure why. I got this error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException

Comment: So i checked and the label is overlapping the input tag. you can do following to click male driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "register-switch").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "label")[0].click()

Comment: And if you want to click female change 0 with 1

Comment: thank you!!!! I am trying to use the same approach on this page for Has your state notified you to file an SR22 (certificate of financial responsibility)? but using the example above it's still not working?

Comment: Use this driver.find_element(By.ID, "sr22Radio1").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "label")[0].click(). 
0 for yes 1 for no

Comment: First, try to get the element you if not visible then try to find its parent. That's the trick for webpage scrapping

Comment: Thank you! I am just learning how to do all this , so I appreciate your guidance. Do you have any books or resources you'd recommend?

Comment: You are welcome. best wishes for you

Comment: i started with this https://developers.google.com/edu/python

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to write a whole page to a .csv?

Comment: Is there a way to collect form fields without specifying the actual field? Depending on what zip code you enter, different fields may be available. It would be very time consuming to go through each state to see the different options.

Comment: No, eventually you have to find all the rage you want to scrape. E.g. input, text area etc.